# Does Azure table storage support Asian languages?

Tags: azure, multilingual, azure-table-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I'm creating a multilingual application in Azure. The base language is English. For storage, I use Azure table storage and DocumentDB. Want to know if Azure Table storage and DocumentDB supports Asian languages like Chinese and Arabic?

Are there any constraints around the use of table storage for multi-lingual applications?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Table Storage does support languages like Chinese and Arabic. For entity attributes you can use the characters as is however if you're using them as your values for `PartitionKey` and/or `RowKey`, please ensure that you encode them properly as these are passed as part of the URL for certain operations.

I haven't tried the same in DocumentDB personally but I am quite certain that the same will be supported there as well. Again I suspect there would be similar restriction on using these characters for `Id` property of the document.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav Mantri!

Answer (score 1):

Azure Storage Table supports **String type** which is essentially .NET string type which supports multi-lingual characters by default.

As shown in the sample Azure Storage Table below, it allows Asian languages content such as Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Arabic, Hindi etc.

[image]

Comment: If you think it's helpful to others, appreciate you can mark it as helpful